# how to add new worksheet in newly created excel file

Tags: java

With the help of below code, I am able to create new excel file on my desktop. But when I open it, gives the error. Also I am not able to add new worksheet in it and names of columns. Could you please help me to create a worksheet and desired in the newly created file, with below code. Thanks a lot.

```
public class SQLTest {

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmnt = null;
    ResultSet RS = null;
    String TestCaseWorkbook = null;
    String TestCaseSheet = null;

    public void getTestCases() throws SQLException, IOException{
        String path = "C:\\Users\\A592013\\Desktop\\newIndexSheet.xls";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ= "+path);
        stmnt = conn.createStatement();
        File f3=new File(path);
        if(!f3.exists())
        f3.createNewFile();

    }
    public static void main (String [] args) throws SQLException, IOException
    {
        SQLTest st = new SQLTest();
        st.getTestCases();  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is creating an empty file which happens to have `xls` extension. To create valid XLS workbook you'll probably need some library. I recommend [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

Here's usage example:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("myWorkbook.xls"));
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook()) {
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("My worksheet");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Hello Excel!");

    workbook.write(fos);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```